# $f(x)=\{x+[\log (2+x)]\} +\{x+[\log (2+x^2)]\}....\{x+[\log (2+x^{10})]\}$. Find number of solutions for $f(x)=x$

Tags: functions

The statement simplifies into

$$f(x)=10\{x\}$$

So
$$10\{x\}=x$$
$$10\{x\}=[x]+\{x\}$$

$$9\{x\}=[x]$$

Then
$$0\le [x] <9$$

$$\implies [x]\in \{0,1,2,3...,8\}$$

How do I find number values of $x$ from here?

Comment: If you are assuming $[\log (2 +x^k)]$ is always an integer so $\{x+[\log(2+k^k)]\}=\{x\}$ then I have wonder who on earth would make up such a covoluted pointlessly obfiscated question, that I *have* to wonder are you interpreting it correctly?  ... oh, well.  If $10\{x\} = x$ the $9\{x\}=x -\{x\}\in \mathbb Z$ so $\{x\}= \frac k9$ and $x = m + \frac k9$ for some integers $k,m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x = n + r$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $0\le r < 1$ then

$10r = n+r$ so $9r = n$ so $r = \frac k9$ where $k = 0,....,8$.

And $9r = n$ and $r=\frac k9$ then $n=k$.

So $x = n + \frac n9$ for $n=0....8$.

....

But .... are you sure you are interpetting the question correctly?  Or was this the result that came out of the solving of  a more complicated question?  I can't imagine what kind of pervert would deliberately set up such an pointlessly obfuscated and obscured question.

Are you sure $[]$ means greatest integer... an not, you know, just brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by $[x]$ you mean the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.
Let $x=I+f$, where $I \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq f < 1$. Then based on $f(x)=10\{x\}$, we get
\begin{align*}
10f&=I+f\\
I&=9f.
\end{align*}
Since $I$ is an integer and $f \in [0,1)$, thus $f=\frac{I}{9} \in \{0,\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}, \frac{3}{9}, \ldots , \frac{8}{9}\}$ for $I =0, 1,2, \ldots, 8$ respectively.
So the solutions are
$$x=I+f \in \left\{0, 1+\frac{1}{9}, \, 2+\frac{2}{9}, \, \ldots , 8+\frac{8}{9}\right\}=\color{red}{\left\{0, \frac{10}{9}, \frac{20}{9}, \ldots , \frac{80}{9}\right\}}.$$

Comment: Well, the answer is not infinite. I don't know the answer, but it's definitely not inifinite

Comment: @Aditya This is **under the assumption** that your reduction of the actual function in your title to $f(x)=10\{x\}$ is correct.

Comment: Well, is it correct?

Comment: @Aditya I have edited my answer. I think I misunderstood what you were asking. See now.

Comment: If "whether this is correct" is part of your question, you should say so explicitly (in the body of your question).